# quicksort code in java is not running properly?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am stuck on this from a while now... the array is not being properly sorted and the end is not decrementing can someone help out on what mistake I am exactly making here?
I tried and looked for hours but cannot find the bug exactly. You can clearly see in the output that end is not decrementing and the sorting of the array is not proper as 17 is last and 45 is second last element. Also there is Error of ArrayOutOfBounds.

code:

```
     public class Program{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] ar={4,5,6,3,10,12,45,17};
    int l=0;
    int h=ar.length-1;

    quickSort(ar,l,h);


}
    static void quickSort(int [] arr,int lb,int ub){
    int z;
    if(lb<ub){
    z=partition(arr,lb,ub);
    quickSort(arr,lb,z-1);
    quickSort(arr,z+1,ub);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}


static int partition(int [] a,int lb,int ub){
    int pivot=a[lb];
    int start=lb;
    int end=ub;
   //If I put end=ub-1 here then it shows index-1. 
   //so I have not options left to do that the Error is coming eitherway.
    System.out.println("start is "+start);
    System.out.println("End is "+end);

    while(start<end){
        while(a[start]<=pivot){
            start++;
        }
        while(a[end]>pivot){
            end--;
        }
        if(start<end){
        int temp0=a[start];
        int temp1=a[end];
        a[start]=temp1;
        a[end]=temp0;
        }

    }
        int temp2=a[lb];
        int temp3=a[end];
        a[lb]=temp3;
        a[end]=temp2;
        return end;
}
}

output:
start is 0
End is 7
3
4
6
5
10
12
45
17
start is 2
End is 7
3
4
5
6
10
12
45
17
start is 4
End is 7
3
4
5
6
10
12
45
17
start is 5
End is 7
3
4
5
6
10
12
45
17
start is 6
End is 7


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 8
    at Program.partition(Program.java:35)
    at Program.quickSort(Program.java:16)
    at Program.quickSort(Program.java:18)
    at Program.quickSort(Program.java:18)
    at Program.quickSort(Program.java:18)
    at Program.quickSort(Program.java:18)
    at Program.main(Program.java:9)
```

Comment: *"the array is not being properly sorted and the end is not decrementing"* - how have you determined this? Give an example of an input, expected result and actual result. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: The inner while loop (`while(a[start]<=pivot)`) goes out of bounds in this example, because it does not get caught by the outer start<end loop

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 1):

In the partition function, along with the condition a[start]<= pivot add the condition start<=ub and in the a[end]>pivot add the condition end>=lb
It will not give  ArrayOutOfBounds error.
The above code works logic works fine in C but in java you require these 2 conditions in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class QuickSort 
{ 
    int partition(int arr[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        int pivot = arr[high]; 
        int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element 
        for (int j=low; j<high; j++) 
        { 
            // If current element is smaller than the pivot 
            if (arr[j] < pivot) 
            { 
                i++; 

                // swap arr[i] and arr[j] 
                int temp = arr[i]; 
                arr[i] = arr[j]; 
                arr[j] = temp; 
            } 
        } 

        // swap arr[i+1] and arr[high] (or pivot) 
        int temp = arr[i+1]; 
        arr[i+1] = arr[high]; 
        arr[high] = temp; 

        return i+1; 
    } 

    void sort(int arr[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        if (low < high) 
        { 
            /* pi is partitioning index, arr[pi] is 
            now at right place */
            int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 

            // Recursively sort elements before 
            // partition and after partition 
            sort(arr, low, pi-1); 
            sort(arr, pi+1, high); 
        } 
    } 

    /* A utility function to print array of size n */
    static void printArray(int arr[]) 
    { 
        int n = arr.length; 
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); 
        System.out.println(); 
    } 

    // Driver program 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int arr[] = {4,5,6,3,10,12,45,17}; 
        int n = arr.length; 

        QuickSort ob = new QuickSort(); 
        ob.sort(arr, 0, n-1); 

        System.out.println("sorted array"); 
        printArray(arr); 
    } 
}
```

OUTPUT:
sorted array
3 4 5 6 10 12 17 45

the above code works for the array you have defined you can use this code,If you still have confusing about quick sort you are free to ask in comments.